# What does a variable declared as external mean when there is a definition provided?

Tags: xquery

If I have

```
declare variable $var as xs:string external := "test";
```

What does this mean? Does it mean that a value for $var can be set for this variable from an external context and if none is specified that "test" is the value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

It's a new feature of XQuery 3.0 (Section 4.16 of [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-30/#doc-xquery30-VarDefaultValue)).